# How to Show Related Products by word from address

Tags: php

I have this code for displaying the latest topics

I want to update this code to
show similar topics from part of the title only or a word from the title

```
<?php
  $fresh_song = $database->query('SELECT tag
    FROM search
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT ' . $freshsong)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  //var_dump($fresh_song);
  foreach ($fresh_song as $fsong) {
    //   print_r($fsong);
    $fsong = ucwords($fsong['tag']);
    ?>
    <a  href="<?php echo mp3_url($fsong); ?>" title="<?php echo toAscii($fsong); ?> mp3" class="list-group-item"><?php echo toAscii($fsong); ?></a>
    <?php
  }?>
```

This is the address code

```
<?php echo (isset($final_result[0]))?$final_result[0]['title']:''; ?>
```

Can I do that?

Comment: What is `$final_result`?

Comment: this is the address
<?php echo (isset($final_result[0]))?$final_result[0]['title']:''; ?>

Comment: If you have more to add to the question, click the Edit button. I already fixed the formatting that was preventing us from seeing that line.'

Comment: Are you asking how to write a search form?

Comment: $final_result This is the title or name of the article in a file called result.php

Comment: But how is it related to the code at the top that displays from the DB?